# ¿como cambiar de color un boton por cada click?

Tags: javascript, bootstrap

necesito que al dar click en un boton que esta verde, se ponga rojo, y si esta rojo se vuelva a poner verde. actualmente utilizo **bootstrap** podria ser que al dar click sea danger y al darle de nuevo sea primary. se que se hace con JS pero la verdad no se como. de antemano muchas gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Utiliza el metodo [`.toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) de jquery donde puedes cambiar una clase o la otra dependiendo de cual este seleccionada:

```js
$("#mi-boton").click(function(){
  $(this).toggleClass("btn-danger btn-success");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel=stylesheet>
<button id="mi-boton" class="btn btn-danger">boton</button>
```

En este ejemplo segun de clic cambia entre la clase `.btn-danger` o `.btn-success`.

Comment: pero para este caso si lo implemento de esa manera pasaria para todos los botones , no?. como podria como colocar un id o algo asi.

Comment: Si, puedes agregar un id para que solo te funcione en un solo elemento y no en todos. Actualize la respuesta haciendolo funcionar con el id del elemento.

Comment: amigo mil gracias, eso era lo que necesitaba.